# Rating architectural efficiency

Tags: performance, architecture, metrics, software-quality

How would you rate  the efficiency of a certain design?

What are your variables?

I can think of:

- Coupling
- Design Patterns use
- Language idioms use.
- Scalability.
- High-viability.
- Code Reuse.
- Flexibility.
- Robustness to errors.
- Testability.
- Design implications on resource use and memory.
- Portability.
- Usage of the correct programming paradigm.
- Design implications on run-time efficiency.
- Encapsulation.

How would you  calculate such metrics?

I've heard of program metrics as a tool  but I have no idea what they are and how to compute them.

I thank anyone who's willing to help.

EDIT:
Here is a [blog entry](http://omerprogramming.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/program-metrics-and-architectural-analysis/) about the subject from my newborn blog.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "efficiency" in this context?

Comment: Comparing to other design, does this design work better?

Comment: Anyone else?
I need more suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to take into account the following metrics either:

1. Scalability.
2. Highviability.

And regarding to your suggestions I don't think memory could be the metric for design efficiency, since it's more implementation based.

---

**EDIT:** (After a comment regarding analytic formula)
I don't think you can find an ultimate formula for computing design efficiency, since it's very subjective. But you can adopt some statistic techniques, define the metrics which really important for you in the design. Afterward define for each metric its weight. Now find different use cases and check how does your design fit them in each metric and give them a grade. After all this you can normalize and compute the value with V= Sum(W_i*G_i)/Sum(W_i), where W_i is weight and G_i is a grade. This way you can specify whatever is important for you in the design and calculate accordingly.

Comment: Yes but how would you provide a formula that will calculate such rating?

Comment: Are you looking for analytic formula to calculate efficiency?

Comment: This is for a program I am writing.
So the user should grade what is more important in this particular design and by that calculate how much the design is efficient?

Comment: Right, but it totally depend on how complicated you want it to be. For example if you want, that some part somehow correlate with each other you to extend the formula and somehow define relation.

Comment: How exactly would you do such a thing?
It needs to be as expressive and extensive as possible.

Comment: Look, this topic is a good research point. Almost everything you have to do empirically, I mean there are a lot off possible solutions and different definitions you may or may not to take in consideration while implementing such formula for your application. For example you can find code reuse and pattern usage can be considered as correlated one, an easy case is linear dependency, but still you have to find empirically how to define it.

Comment: Ok, forgo the formula for now.
I need the most criterias I can find.
What about sub categories?
If a design uses a pattern but it's the wrong one will this reduce the rating?

Comment: Do you want to chat via email instead of commenting here?

Comment: no problem.
the_drow at walla dot com

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tools out there that can do this for you. One I've used is [Checkstyle - Metrics](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_metrics.html).

I can't say really consider these metrics when designing, but use them on slow/lazy afternoons when I'm looking for a bit of code to attack.

Answer (score 1):

Code reuse. While you perhaps can't count it as a positive value you can count it's underuse as a negative value and get a cumulative penalty score for bad code reuse.

Comment: And how would you say it's important from 1-10.
How do you decide that it is more important then coupling for example?